# Value in angular scope getting undefined

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have a scenario for deleting items.
For this, first I get a list of values with particular condition. The retrieved values whill be shown in the UI with radio buttons to choose the particular item to choose for deleting.

I have given the value for the radio buttons to be the id of the retrieved items. This id is used in angularJS method for deleting. Currently getting undefined value in the angular function inside the controller.

My angular controller is as below:

```
mainApp.controller("deleteToDoController", function($scope,$http) {
$scope.toDoList = {};
$scope.getToDo = function(){
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/webservice-4.0/rest/todo/"+$scope.status;
    $http.get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.toDoList = angular.fromJson(response.data);
    });
}
$scope.deleteToDo = function(){
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/webservice-4.0/rest/todo/delete/"+$scope.deleteId;
    $http.get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.toDoList = angular.fromJson(response.data);
    });
}

});
```

My html page code is :

```
<div ng-controller="deleteToDoController">
<form ng-submit="getToDo()">
    ToDo Status:
    <input type="radio" ng-model="status" value="completed"/>Completed<input type="radio" ng-model="status" value="pending"/>Not Completed
    <input type="submit" value="View To Do"/><br>
    <div ng-repeat = "toDo in toDoList">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="deleteId" value="{{toDo.id}}"/>Task : {{toDo.name}}<br>
    </div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="deleteToDo()">Delete</button><br>
</form>
```

Appreciated!!!!

Comment: where do you get undefined?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Getting undefined inside deleteToDo() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `deletedId` have been created inside `ng-repeat` child scope. You won't that `scope` variable outside `ng-repeat`, like you were trying to pass it in `ng-click`

You have to do following .

1. use `Dot rule` while defining model, so that Prototypal Inheritance will help to pass reference of variable to child scope.
2. Use `ControllerAs` pattern.

**Html**

```
<form ng-submit="getToDo()">
    ToDo Status:
    <input type="radio" ng-model="status" value="completed"/>Completed<input type="radio" ng-model="status" value="pending"/>Not Completed
    <input type="submit" value="View To Do"/><br>
    <div ng-repeat = "toDo in toDoList">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="tobeDeleted.deleteId" 
           value="{{toDo.id}}"/>
        Task : {{toDo.name}}<br>
    </div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="deleteToDo()">Delete</button><br>
</form>
```

**Using Dot Rule**

```
//define model
$scope.tobeDeleted = {}; //then place deleted property here
//you could easily access `$scope.tobeDeleted.deletedId` inside a controller
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, Could you please reccomend a solution for this issue?

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, that was the issue

Answer (score 2):

Your $scope.deleteId Will be undefiend. Your function should have a parameter **deleteId**,change the function as

```
$scope.deleteToDo = function(deletId){
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/webservice-4.0/rest/todo/delete/"+ deleteId;
    $http.get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.toDoList = angular.fromJson(response.data);
    });
}
```

make sure you pass Id Inside the html also,

```
<input type="button" ng-click="deleteToDo(toDo.id)">Delete</button><br>
```

**EDIT**

Since your delete button is outside **`ng-repeat`** You should use dot operator with **`ng-model`** for the **deleteId**

define a **`$scope`** variable as,

$scope.deleteItem = {};

and your HTML as,

```
<div ng-repeat = "toDo in toDoList">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="deleteItem.deleteId" value="{{toDo.id}}"/>
</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="deleteToDo()">Delete</button><br>
```

and your controller as,

```
$scope.deleteToDo = function(){
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/webservice-4.0/rest/todo/delete/"+$scope.deleteItem.deleteId;
    $http.get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.toDoList = angular.fromJson(response.data);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried that too, Its getting undefined in that case also.

Comment: <input type="button" ng-click="deleteToDo(toDo.id)">Delete</button><br>

Comment: @PankajParkar its just a sample